# ArcGIS Desktop to ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-online, arcgis-10.5

BACKSTORY:

I am currently in college (a nursing major - nothing to do with GIS or engineering), but I work for a local government's engineering department during the summers.  After a few changes with employees, I was assigned to keep the township's GIS mapping up to date.  I have been able to teach myself enough about ArcGIS Desktop to be able to create and update features in ArcMap, link to existing servers, and publish maps for ArcReader.

PROBLEM:

The local government is split into two different offices, with both needing the same maps.  We need a way for both offices to be able to update the maps without jeopardizing the other's work.  As of right now, we are only using one of our subscriptions, with employees from both offices using one computer to update their work and then using an external hard drive to transfer the files that are hyperlinked and the projects to the other office's server.  It is time consuming and a waste of our second subscription.

ATTEMPTED SOLUTIONS:

Since we have two subscriptions to ArcGIS Desktop (one for each office), we have decided that using our complimentary ArcGIS Online service is our best bet.  I have been able to create a web map that automatically opens to our area and connect to a server to add the parcel information, but I am unsure of the best way to connect our information from our desktop to online.  All of our layers are in four geodatabases. One solution may be to convert our geodatabases to a file, such as .csv, that is accepted by ArcGIS Online.  We have also attempted without success to connect our accounts using a portal or server, but we are not 100% sure we are doing this correctly.  I have been able to create a layer package in ArcMap and upload it to ArcGIS Online, but when I go to open the layer package, it only gives me an option to open it in ArcGIS Desktop, which doesn't help at all.

No employees that currently work for our organization have formal GIS training, though we do pay for a company to help us.  Unfortunately, the employee assigned to us will not offer any tips and only attempts to sell us a different online GIS system (but that system will not work for our needs/the cost would be far too much for the amount of information we would need to add to our online map).

How do we get our current ArcMap documents into ArcGIS Online?

Comment: We don't need backstory. It sounds like your **real** problem is the contractor who refuses to help. My COTR would issue a Stop Work on the contract if I told them I would only help solve problems if I got to choose the sotfware they use. I'd recommend that you have your management contact your Esri rep. Maybe they can deploy a solution engineer to get you started.

Comment: Share your map as feature service to online. Each of you can create local copy for editing and synchronise edits.